# How to include some library within the Yocto SDK

Tags: cross-compiling, embedded-linux, yocto, qt5.5

I have built `marble` library and `meta-qt5-toolchain` using bitbake.
I have installed SDK in my PC succesfully.But not able to find marble library in the `/usr/local/oe-core(x64)/`

How can I include libraries from `marble` package in the SDK.
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure in your recipe to have

```
BBCLASSEXTEND += "native nativesdk"
```

Explanation

One can use `BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"` to bake binaries for the host  architecture (native) and for target sdk architecture.

The target sdk architecture is described in the `SDKMACHINE` variable and the host architecture is the architecture of the machine executing bitbake. `BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"` will alow you to bake recipes that are "virtual" using the suffix native ( so `${PN}-native`) and the prefix nativesdk (so `nativesdk-${PN}`)

Then, do

```
bitbake <recipe> -c populate_sdk
```

Hope it helps