# Adding library to Yocto native sysroot

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe

I'm trying to build this pkcs#11 proxy for use with Yocto native build tools.
https://github.com/SUNET/pkcs11-proxy

Unfortunately it needs some libraries

```
| /home/user/build/tmp-glibc/hosttools/ld: cannot find -lseccomp: No such file or directory
```

Fortunately libseccomp is included in Yocto `meta-poky/meta/recipes-support/libseccomp/libseccomp_2.5.3.bb`

So adding this to my recipe should do

```
DEPENDS = "libseccomp-native"
```

But

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'libseccomp-native' (but virtual:native:/home/user/meta-deif/recipes-devtools/pkcs11-proxy/pkcs11-proxy.bb DEPENDS on or otherwise requires it). Close matches:
  libcomps-native
  libsm-native
  libsoup-native
ERROR: Required build target 'machine' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['machine', 'bootstrapfiles', 'pil-u-boot', 'pkcs11-proxy-native', 'libseccomp-native']
```

I tried a lot of variants on the DEPENDS but none works. How I I get libseccomp include in my native sysroot

Edit: So far my workaround is to add the .so file to the docker container.

Comment: try it with DEPENDS = "libseccomp" , is meta-poky in your bblayers.conf in local/conf/bblayers.conf ?

Comment: I Think that I tried all possible combinations in DEPENDS including this.

Answer (score 0):

[libseccomp](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/180709/) is the name of the recipe. The `-native` suffix from this [wiki](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Technical_FAQ#What_does_.22native.22_mean.3F):

> The "native" suffix identifies recipes (and variants of recipes) that produce files intended for the build host, as opposed to the target machine. This is usually for tools that are needed during the build process (such as automake).

The recipe is provided by `openembedded-core` which should be in the `meta-poky/meta/` layer as you found. You can check the recipe is available by doing

```
bitbake-layers show-recipes
```

To find something similar to:

```
...
libseccomp:
  meta                 2.5.3
...
```

You can try and build just `libseccomp` with `bitbake libseccomp`. Or add it into your image with:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " libseccomp"
```

But the `DEPENDS` variable should bring it in.

---

To get the `-native` version of the package, you have to add

```
BBCLASSEXTEND += "native nativesdk"
```

to your recipe, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45256758/how-to-include-my-library-in-sdk).

Comment: Nothing of this seems to help. I tried to add BBCLASSEXTEND += "native nativesdk" to both my recipe and to the libseccomp recipe without any luck.